# Export excel from visual c#

Tags: c#, excel

I use from this issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084 to exporting to excel from Visual C# and I have not any problem.

To set cell border I use below codes:

```
oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
oSheet.get_Range("A2", "J2").Borders.LineStyle = true;
```

and above code is working good.

but now I want set cell border only for odd rows.

so for this reason I want use for loop like as I have defined below:

```
for(i=1,i<=6,i++)
{
    oSheet.get_Range( , ).Borders.LineStyle = true; // only for odd rows.
}
```

but I don't know how I must change above syntax that in each loop its change according to the variable.

Comment: A modulus of 2 should return zero: `if ((i % 2) == 0)`. That should define even rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take every other row, you can rewrite the for loop with step 2:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i+=2)                 // only for odd rows.
{
    string c1 = "A" + i.ToString();
    string c2 = "J" + i.ToString();
    oSheet.get_Range(c1, c2).Borders.LineStyle = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# DataGridView Export to Excel :

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=pubs;Integrated Security=True";
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Authors";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        connection.Open();
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Authors_table");
        connection.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "Authors_table";
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        Int16 i, j;

        xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 2; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = dataGridView1[j, i].Value.ToString();
            }
        }

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"c:\csharp.net-informations.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
    }

    private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Export databse to excel file

http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-export.htm

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment: you simply need to check the remainder of division by 2 to find odd or even rows.

To only add the border line style for odd rows (i.e. your first row, third row, fifth row, etc.) something similar to the following code should do:

```
for(i=1,i<=6,i++)
{
    if ((i % 2) == 1)
    {
        oSheet.get_Range( , ).Borders.LineStyle = true; // only for odd rows.
    }
}
```